# Can't communicate between 2 Linux server

Tags: ubuntu

I have 2 servers - one running ubuntu server 19.04 with docker and multiple containers, and the other running OMV 4.
both are connected directly to my router with a static IP.
I can SSH into both from my windows laptop, I can ping both from my windows laptop, each of them can ping other devices on the LAN, and WAN, but they cant ping or SSH each-other. firewall is off in both. I'm using only the IP addresses, never domain names.

tried netcat with a random port between the 2- nothing
tried traceroute between the 2 - shows nothing (only asterisks)

Please help.

**update** - it seems it's related to my 2 NICs on the OMV server. They are connected as an aggregated link to provide a 2Gbps connection, and once I disconnect the ethernet cable from the secondary one, connection between the 2 works. like I said, the other devices on the network communicate with it normally...

Comment: It might help if you post the output of `ip a` from both of them and what addresses you're using with SSH.

Comment: If removing one cable from an aggregated link makes the connection work, then something is likely wrong with the set-up of the aggregated link. For example, both cables must be connected to the same network segment, and sometimes into the same switch, depending on aggregation mode chosen, and the switch the aggregated links are plugged into.

Comment: They need to be connected to port 1 and 2 in the case of my router. Though the fact that it somewhat works is throwing me off :/

Comment: Belatedly... chances are you're bridging your Docker containers with a physical interface rather than the aggregated one